# Run a flash based voice chat without the flash media server

Tags: flash, flash-media-server

Its just a quick question: Is it possible to run a falsh based voice chat without using the flash media server and instead using some kind of peer to peer connection? (just one to one connection, one to many connections are not needed)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, [Codename Cirrus (previously codename Stratus)](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/)

Comment: Sounds great. Is there an open source alternative?

Comment: @ Filipe Santos - it's possible in theory, but never heard about it

Comment: how does one use cirrus without buying a flash server?

Comment: @Tom - it's p2p which means you don't need a server to use it. You need to get a developer key from adobe (at http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=cirrus) and connect your app to rtmfp://p2p.rtmfp.net/_your_key_/. To connect to another app instance you'll need to create a `new NetStream(connection_connected_to_rtmfp://p2p.rtmfp.net, peerID);`, where peerID is `NetConnection.nearID` of the instance you're connecting to.